# What are some Outlook Plugins/Add-ins that take the invitees of a meeting and add them to the body of an invite?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, plugins, calendar, outlook-addin

I would like to automatically, or at the press of 1 or 2 clicks/buttons, insert the list of invitees of my meeting into my invite in Outlook, at meeting creation time.

I have seen this done once before and thought it was a great idea.  I have been able to replicate this invitee list, but only by manually copying/pasting.  I have not been able to find any add-ins or plugins (they're different words for the same thing as far as Outlook is concerned) that claim to do this.  I've actually been having a hard time find add-ins in general.

Are there any add-ins that do what I am looking for?  Perhaps something close?

What are some reputable places to find Outlook add-ins without catching some ITDs? (Internet Transmitted Diseases)?

I have Outlook 2013 connected to an on-prem Exchange environment, if that matters for the add-ins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to search for an add-in. Here is the example of simple VBA macro:

```
Sub InsertRecipients()
    Set objInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set objItem = objInspector.CurrentItem

    Text = ""
    For Each objRecip In objItem.Recipients
        Text = Text & " " & objRecip.Name
    Next

    If Len(Text) > 0 Then
        Set objSelection = objInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection
        objSelection.Text = Text
        objSelection.Move
    End If
End Sub
```

Just press ALT+F11 in Outlook and then put this macro to ThisOutlookSession module. Press CTRL+S to save. After that you'll be able to either run this macro from **DEVELOPER** ribbon tab (enable in first in ribbon properties) using the **Macros** button or just add your custom button on a ribbon that runs this macro.

Comment: Thanks for the VB Script.  I've never used anything like that before, but I'll try that out.

Comment: I'd like to add the SMTP address as well, and I am finding a hard time finding documentation on VB.  This is where I am at so far, and it's not displaying the SMTP address.  Do you have any ideas?

Sub InsertRecipients()
    Set objInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set objItem = objInspector.CurrentItem

    Text = "Meeting invitees:" & vbCrLf
    For Each objRecip In objItem.Recipients
        Set pa = objRecip.PropertyAccessor
        Text = Text & " " & objRecip.Name & " " & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) & vbCrLf
    Next
...

Comment: You can get SMTP address for external users like that: objRecip.Address. For internal Exchange recipients you have to do something like that: objRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress

Comment: I don't suppose there's 1 command that gives me the SMTP address regardless of internal/external Exchange user is there?  How were you able to find that information?  I was not able to use DuckDuckGo to find it.  Is there a specific site that has these commands?

Comment: You can check objRecip.AddressEntry.Type property. Its value is "EX" for Exchange recipients and "SMTP" for external ones.